# Understanding memory situation for tuning a PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: postgresql, linux-kernel, ubuntu-22.04, postgresql-15

I'm trying to better understand my performance / tuning options for a PostgreSQL database.

System:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- aarch64, 80 cores, 256 GB RAM
- PostgreSQL 15

Right now, the shared buffer size is configured as `shared_buffers = 128MB`. I understand, increasing the buffer will likely boost performance. However, it is also my understanding, that I need to be aware of possible limits imposed by the Linux kernel.

`ipcs -l` returns:

```
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18446744073709551612
min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

It is my understanding that `18014398509465599` is the maximum size of shared memory supported for a single process. Is this correct?

If I'm switching on `--human`, the output is:

```
max total shared memory = 16E
```

What does `16E` mean?

My key question: What is the maximum size I could set the shared buffers to, given my current kernel? Sorry if this question might sound stupid.

I appreciate any help and explaination.

Answer (score 1):

The System V shared memory limits don't apply, since PostgreSQL has switched to using POSIX shared memory long ago.

16E would be 16 Exabytes.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz. In the situation I described, would that mean that I can safely increase the PostgreSQL `shared_buffers` value from the current 128MB to a higher value? Would it make sense to give it like 1GB?

Comment: Probably. That depends on your data and most of all on your workload.

Comment: Exabytes see [here](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-is-an-exabyte/).  That is just 1  Exabyte.